# problem: Failed to find byte code for org/jaxen/SimpleNamespaceContext. after Import Java Client for GeoNames

Tags: android, android-studio

I get error after i followed this video [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1N7BuN3sVg)

I implemented project(':geonames-1.1.14') and project(':jdom-1.0') without problem.

error comes when I run the app.

Error: Failed to find byte code for org/jaxen/SimpleNamespaceContext

```
org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.

Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to find byte code for org/jaxen/SimpleNamespaceContext

Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed 
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to find byte code for org/jaxen/SimpleNamespaceContext

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to find byte code for org/jaxen/SimpleNamespaceContext

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to find byte code for org/jaxen/SimpleNamespaceContext
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.AsmUtils.lambda$static$0(AsmUtils.java:89)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.AsmUtils.loadClass(AsmUtils.java:307)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.AsmUtils.readClassAndInterfaces(AsmUtils.java:165)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.AsmUtils.loadClass(AsmUtils.java:278)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.IncrementalVisitor.instrumentClass(IncrementalVisitor.java:342)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.transformToClasses2Format(InstantRunTransform.java:406)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.lambda$doTransform$3(InstantRunTransform.java:268)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.lambda$null$4(InstantRunTransform.java:297)
```

this not all error code.

Answer (score 0):

I have an app with `geonames-1.1.14.jar` and `jdom-1.0.jar` as dependencies.
When I build the app with `minifyEnabled true` this warning appears:

> R8 warnings: (1 warning)
>   Missing class: org.jaxen.SimpleNamespaceContext

Don't know if it's exactly the same your problem, but one solution I found is to include also the [Jaxen library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jaxen/jaxen) in the `build.gradle` of my app:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'jaxen:jaxen:1.2.0'
}
```